# Select rows of a pandas DataFrame with at most one null entry

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

If I need to choose from a dataframe where columns col1 and col2 must follow the condition that **atleast one of these columns must be not null**.

Right now, I am trying to perform below but it doesn't work

```
df=df.loc[(df['Cat1_L2'].isnull()) & (df['Cat2_L3'].isnull())==False]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Setup**
(Modifying U8-Forward's data)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Cat1_L2':[1,np.nan,3, np.nan], 'Cat3_L3': [np.nan,3,4, np.nan]})
df

   Cat1_L2  Cat3_L3
0      1.0      NaN
1      NaN      3.0
2      3.0      4.0
3      NaN      NaN
```

---

#### Indexing with `isna` + `sum`

Fixing your code, ensure the number of `True` cases (corresponding to `NaN` in columns) is lesser than 2.

```
df[df[['Cat1_L2', 'Cat3_L3']].isna().sum(axis=1) < 2]

   Cat1_L2  Cat3_L3
0      1.0      NaN
1      NaN      3.0
2      3.0      4.0
```

---

#### `dropna` with `thresh`

```
df.dropna(subset=['Cat1_L2', 'Cat3_L3'], thresh=1)

   Cat1_L2  Cat3_L3
0      1.0      NaN
1      NaN      3.0
2      3.0      4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to loop over every row using `itertuples()`. Beaware that this is computationally expensive.

**1 - Create list that chceks your condition for each row using itertuples()**

```
condition_list = []
for row in df.itertuples():
    if (row.Cat1_L2 != None) or (row.Cat2_L3 != None):
       condition_list.append(1)
    else:
       condition_list.append(0)
```

**2. Convert list to pandas series**

```
 condition_series = pd.Series(condition_list)
```

**3. Append series to original df**

```
df['condition_column'] = condition_series.values
```

**4. Filter df**

```
df_new = df[df.condition_column == 1]
del df_new['condition_column']
```

Comment: Thanks for the upvote, and I appreciate the fact that you've answered. Please keep it up, and keep learning. +1